# Can I install bazel on Ubuntu 18.04.1?

Tags: installation, bazel, ubuntu-18.04

I just want to know, if it's possible to install [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. 
 Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bazel is officially supported on 18.04. It's not reflected on the documentation yet, but it's fully tested on the Bazel CI.

Answer (score 4):

You can just follow the below codes to run bazel on 16.04

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
$ echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list
$ curl https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install bazel
```

Answer (score 1):

You can but it is not supported, if you have a look at the [Documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-ubuntu.html).

Comment: The documentation is slightly outdated - Bazel is fully tested on 18.04 on our CI, so it's officially supported.